# Error in my call : Incorrect Argument Label In Call (have 'key:', expected 'coder:')

Tags: ios, swift, nssortdescriptor

I am receiving an error in my method that sorts my table view cells in Swift.

The error comes from the `func loadDataFromDatabase()` on the line:

```
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: sortPriority)
```

My table View Controller file:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class noteTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var notes = [Note]()

    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? {
        return (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    }

    func loadDataFromDatabase() {
        let settings = UserDefaults.standard

        let sortPriority = settings.string(forKey: Constants.kPriority)

        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Note")

        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: sortPriority)

        let sortDescriptorsArray = [sortDescriptor]

        request.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptorsArray

        do {
            notes = try context.fetch(request)
        } catch let errer as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you're doing is confusing compiler with the `init(coder:)` initializer. To use the initializer you want, you also need to provide `ascending` argument:

```
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: sortPriority, ascending: true)
```

Comment: Thank you this fixed one error, now I am having an error inside of my do loop. It says "Cannot convert value of type 'NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>' to expected argument type 'NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResults>'"

Comment: That's probably because `fetch` receives a `NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>` as parameter and you're passing a `NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>`.

Comment: What would be the best way around this problem?